# Why did Jesus not know who touched him in Luke 8 :45?

Tags: luke

And Jesus said, 'Who is it that touched me?' and all denying, Peter and those with him said, 'Master, the multitudes press thee, and throng thee, and thou dost say, Who is it that touched me!'

Comment: Related, possible Duplicate (with a more constructive outlook) [Issue of Blood ... Healing Power](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13651/does-the-miracle-of-the-woman-with-an-issue-of-blood-indicate-that-healing-power).

Comment: Also related, possible Duplicate [Delayed Realisation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/45624/luke-842-47-mark-525-35-is-delayed-realization-awareness-proof-of-distinct).

Comment: Also related, possible Duplicate [Healing Power ... Spontaneous](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/13651/does-the-miracle-of-the-woman-with-an-issue-of-blood-indicate-that-healing-power).

Comment: Where does it say Jesus didn't know who touched him?

Comment: Hi @Alex Balillo - could you add a little more detail to your question? Are you asking with respect to omniscience, or something else?

Comment: HoldToTheRod. I would like to know why did he not know who touched him. Does Peter's reply indicate Jesus knew who touched him. Is there anything in the context that say Jesus knew.?

Answer (score 4):

Why did Jesus not know who touched him in Luke 8:45?

The question assumes that Jesus did not know who touched him in Luke 8:45.

> 46 But Jesus said, “Someone touched me; I know that power has gone out from me.”

People were crowding him and touching him. Yet, Jesus singled out a special instance of touching by someone's faith.
He raised the question in order for that person to confess. Confession is good for the soul.

> 47 Then the woman, seeing that she could not go unnoticed, came trembling and fell at his feet. In the presence of **all** the people, she told why she had touched him and how she had been **instantly** healed.

Now everyone knows and her act serves as a testimony for them and for us. Being as gracious as ever, Jesus said to her,

> 48  “Daughter, your faith has healed you. Go in peace.”

Why did Jesus not know who touched him in Luke 8:45?

There is no need to assume that Jesus did not know who touched him in Luke 8:45.
A better question is this: Why did Jesus ask: Who touched me in Luke 8:45?

So that the woman would confess and her act would become a testimony for the world to see.

Comment: I agree - this is how I’ve always interpreted the passage!

Comment: I would add that not just the confession, but also for her to fully express her faith. (Luke 8:48)

Answer (score 1):

Why did Jesus not know who touched him? Luke 8:45

> Jesus said, “Who is the one who touched Me?” And while they were all denying it, Peter said, “Master, the people are crowding and pressing in on You.”

Jesus was a finite, mortal human who depended on God for everything - his miracles, his words, his decisions and plans.

> And Jesus grew in wisdom and stature... Luk2 2:52

> I have not spoken on My own, but the Father who sent Me has commanded Me what to say and how to say it. John 12:49

Jesus didn't have the power or wisdom or knowledge of God while he was on the earth in his flesh and blood body.

Even after his being raised and drawn up to heaven with the Father, he is still not privy to everything, as the Father still gives him what he needs to say. Rev 1:1

So, Jesus is not all knowing - because he either had stopped being God while a man, OR he was never God to begin with and was a *man only* as he said in John 8:40

> But as it is, you are seeking to kill Me, a man who has told you the truth, which I heard from God; this Abraham did not do.

Clearly this passage rules out the 'stopped being God' idea, as it says he heard the truth from God.

If he was God and all-knowing, he could hardly hear from God if he was God. Either he was - according to men's wisdom, or he wasn't - according to the inspired text.

Luke 8:45 is just one of hundreds of passages that says he wasn't!

That's why he didn't know who touched him - just as we wouldn't either.

Comment: Does this mean that this woman is dammed because Jesus doesn't know her ?

Comment: By this same reasoning, God in the garden wasn't God, since he didn't know where Adam was.

Comment: If he chooses to do things in a certain way(e.g. healing a blind man by a process involving dirt, another by his word), should he then be judged inferior simply because he did not do so instantaneously(e.g. Naaman)?

Comment: This passage indeed might be hard for monothelite Trinitarians to explain, but you're overstating how difficult it is for the majority of Trinitarians, who are Chalcedonian.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Except you're dealing with 2 different genres. Gen. 1:1-11 is mythic (in the best sense), Luke 8 is journalistic reportage.

Answer (score 1):

Of course he knew who touched him in that before she could touch him, he must first touch her by his Holy Spirit just as it is in the case of all those who come to Jesus by faith. Jesus's questioning presented the woman the opportunity to step forward and confess. It is that same Holy Spirit that prompts us to come forward and confess our faith.